# Getting version mismatch error while updating into DCTM using java

Tags: java, dfc, documentum-dfc, documentum-dql, dctm

I am trying to update into  DCTM through java code, below is the code snippet

```java
IDfDocument communication = (IDfDocument) getDfSession().getObject(DfId.valueOf(communicationId));
communication.setString(ATTR_STATUS, status);
communication.save();
```

but I am getting the below error

> *Caused by: DfException:: THREAD: be.ing.ca.xpression.DCTM001P-1; MSG: [DM_OBJ_MGR_E_VERSION_MISMATCH]error: "save of object
> 090283e589bf689d of type xx_document failed because of version
> mismatch: old version was 4"; ERRORCODE: 100; NEXT: null*

I thinki am getting this error because there is another process which is trying to modify the object ,and when more than one process try to modify anyobject DCTM throws this exception,

But after lot of searching i dident found any  solution which can solve this error

If anyone knows the solution please reply..

Link that i  refer
http://www.javablog.fr/?s=version+mismatch

Answer (score 1):

Try calling a `fetch()` on the object before doing updates.

```
communication.fetch()
```

There are some optional parameters AFAIK.